# How do I dynamically set the visibility of the SideMenuBar in Codename one?

Tags: java, codenameone

Using the Toolbar class within codenameone, how do I dynamically set the visibility of the SideMenuBar?

I'm using a WebBrowser component, and I only want the SideMenu to be accessible after login.

I achieved the behavior I wanted when I was simply placing commands on a SideMenuBar (METHOD 1), but now that I've switched over to use the Toolbar class for the LnF advantages (METHOD 2), the `hideLeftSideMenuBool` theme constant does not seem to be observed.

```
//METHOD 1
//CHANGING THE THEME DYNAMICALLY HIDES THE SIDEMENUBAR WHEN I'VE SIMPLY 
//ADDED COMMANDS LIKE THIS
current.addCommand(new Command("Home") {
    {
      putClientProperty("place", "side");
    }
});

//METHOD 2
//CHANGING THE THEME DYNAMICALLY DOES NOT HIDE THE SIDEMENUBAR WHEN I'VE
//USED toolbar.addComponentToSideMenu TO ADD BUTTONS WITH COMMANDS 
toolbar = new Toolbar();
current.setToolbar(toolbar);
Button home = new Button("Home");
toolbar.addComponentToSideMenu(home, new Command("Home"){

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    wb.setURL(startURL);
  }
});

...

//I USED THE FOLLOWING CODE TO DYNAMICALLY SET THE THEME AFTER EVALUATING A 
//WebBrowser URI REGARDLESS OF WHICH METHOD WAS USED TO ADD COMMANDS
wb.setBrowserNavigationCallback(new BrowserNavigationCallback() {
  public boolean shouldNavigate(String url) {
    if ((url.indexOf("users/login") != -1)) {
        try {
            //theme_noside.res has hideLeftSideMenuBool set to true
            theme = Resources.openLayered("/theme_noside");
            UIManager.getInstance().setThemeProps(theme.getTheme(theme.getThemeResourceNames()[0]));
            UIManager.getInstance().getLookAndFeel().setMenuBarClass(SideMenuBar.class);
            Display.getInstance().setCommandBehavior(Display.COMMAND_BEHAVIOR_SIDE_NAVIGATION);
            current.refreshTheme();
        }catch(IOException e){
            Log.p(e.toString());
        }
    }
    else {
        try {
            //theme.res has hideLeftSideMenuBool set to false
            theme = Resources.openLayered("/theme");
            UIManager.getInstance().setThemeProps(theme.getTheme(theme.getThemeResourceNames()[0]));
            UIManager.getInstance().getLookAndFeel().setMenuBarClass(SideMenuBar.class);
            Display.getInstance().setCommandBehavior(Display.COMMAND_BEHAVIOR_SIDE_NAVIGATION);
            current.refreshTheme();
        }catch(IOException e){
            Log.p(e.toString());
        }
    }
    return true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Toolbar api only and you don't have to call or change any theme constant.

Make your toolbar final or declare it outside the `beforeShow()` method, so you can access it within inner method `shouldNavigate(String url)`.

All you need to do is call `removeAll()` and then reset the title and add components you want. If toolbar has no command or title, it would be hidden by default.

```
wb.setBrowserNavigationCallback(new BrowserNavigationCallback() {
    public boolean shouldNavigate(String url) {
        if ((url.indexOf("users/login") != -1)) {
            toolbar.removeAll();
            toolbar.setTitleComponent(new Label("My Form", "Title"));
            toolbar.getComponentForm().revalidate();
        } else {
            //Do nothing, since I've already add the commands I want earlier
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Diamond.  Your suggestion got me very close.  I had to call current.revalidate() after toolbar.removeAll() to trigger hiding the toolbar after I emptied it.  I then needed new logic to rebuild the toolbar, when it was to be visible, but you provided the missing link. Much appreciated.